# Linq to Sql ExecuteCommand for CREATE DATABASE

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and I am using LinqToSql for database access.

I want to create a database from a SQL script into my DBMS (SQL Server Express).

When I run my script no SQL Server Management Studio it works with same user connection, however, when I run it from LinqToSql with `ExecuteCommand` it does give errors about I cannot use GO statements. If I remove GO statements and try again, it says CREATE SCHEMA should be the first line of the batch.

Therefore, I am confused, is there any other(better) way of running the sql script, which contains CREATE DATABASE and CREATE SCHEMA statements, from asp.net mvc without these issues.

Thanks,
cas sakal

Here is the content of the script;

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [TESTDB]
CREATE SCHEMA [base] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [base].[TestTable](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
 using (var db = CreateContext()) {
    if (db.DatabaseExists())
      db.DeleteDatabase();
    db.CreateDatabase();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader("prepareDatabase.sql")) {
      var commands = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] {"GO\r"}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      foreach (var cmd in commands) {
        db.ExecuteCommand(cmd);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these task have to be executed from a script? You could use [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) which gives you [programmatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162175.aspx) access to management tasks. e.g [creating a database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205154.aspx)

Comment: I can run them through SQL Server Management Objects but do they work from ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I don't see why not, SMO can just be referenced like any other library.

Answer (score 0):

`GO` is not a valid T-SQL command - it's a command delimiter that SQL Server Management Studio uses. You cannot use `GO` in SQL scripts you want to execute from your own code.

What you need to do is split up that script into two:

- a first `CREATE DATABASE` script that creates the database (and possibly schema)
- a second script that will create the table

You need to execute both one after the other using the `ExecuteCommand` call.